# How to determine how much did I burn through my AWS API gateway plan and how to put a cap on billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've set up an AWS HTTP API gateway, a reverse proxy to my service running on Heroku:

- 1x API gateway
- 1x Route
- 1x Integration
- 1x Custom domain with an SSL certificate

This is all working fine right now.

Although I've spent days studying AWS, two questions still remained unanswered to me:

1. How do I know how much did I burn through my free tier (or any other tier) on AWS?
2. How can I put a cap on API requests/costs so that if I misconfigure something or if somebody attacks my web site, I won't end up paying $$$ in AWS fees?

Thanks!

Comment: For first question, setup AWS budget. For second question, read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-throttling.html

Comment: @AnkushJain Thanks, I was aware of throttling, but it's very hard (almost impossible) to infer a cap based on throttling. If you have 50 parallel requests, max 100 rps, I still get an astronomical number prorated per month. I'm sad that (if) there is no way to protect my client from potential huge charges, as described in my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278375/does-amazon-aws-api-gateway-charge-for-failed-requests-http-status-not-in-200/72280168#72280168