# Does Amazon AWS API gateway charge for failed requests? (HTTP status not in 200-299)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Does Amazon AWS API gateway, namely **HTTP API** gateway (not Lambda functions), charge for failed request? I.e. such requests that made it through to their destination but the return code is other than HTTP 200-299?

To put it in context, I am trying to determine if given that a "bad person" created a `while true; curl http://i-dont-like.com/dummy; done` script could result in a huge AWS charge for the domain owner - if they used AWS HTTP API gateway?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation says - `Pay only for the API calls you receive and the amount of data transferred out`  - https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/ - So indeed, you are paying for the 4xx and 5xx requests as well.

What you can do is to set up a WAF and create a rule to block this kind of behavior.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-i/

Comment: It is very concerning as a simple infinite (especially in parallel) can easily do 1.000 rps x 3600 x 24 = 84M requests per day, a $100 bill/day = $3.000/month. I need to look for an alternative API gateway.

Comment: that is what I am saying, protect your API with WAF, it is relatively cheap